# Networkx Information Centrality

Tags: graph, networkx, node-centrality

I have a network graph which I want to calculate information centrality for. I used the networkx python package but had a problem.

My code is:

`G = nx.read_edgelist('GraphEdge_2011.txt', create_using=nx.DiGraph, delimiter=",", nodetype=int) info = nx.information_centrality(G, weight=None, dtype='float', solver='lu')`

I got an error message: NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for directed type.

My graph shouldn't have any direction. Why do I get this error message and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a directed graph using `nx.DiGraph`. You can make it an undirected graph by changing that to `nx.Graph`.